# Aggregate groups based on index from external object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with a categorical column and some other stuff:

```
>>> np.random.seed(0xFEE7)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(10, size=10), 
                       'B': np.random.randint(10, size=10),
                       'C': np.random.choice(['A', 'B'], size=10)})
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  0  0  B
1  4  0  B
2  6  6  A
3  8  3  B
4  0  2  A
5  8  4  A
6  4  1  B
7  8  7  A
8  4  4  A
9  1  1  A
```

I'd like to be able to apply a groupby done on `C` to another dataframe. For example, let's say

```
>>> ser = df['A'] - df['B']
```

I would like to be able to use the indices in `df.groupby(['C', D])` to compute the means of `ser`. I can compute the group means for a single column, e.g., `C` like this:

```
>>> (df['A'] - df['B']).groupby(df['C']).mean()
C
A   -1.250000
B    3.666667
dtype: float64
```

However, using a multi-index does not work:

```
>>> (df['A'] - df['B']).groupby(df[['C', 'D']]).mean()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jfoxrabinovitz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1678, in groupby
    return groupby_generic.SeriesGroupBy(
  File "C:\Users\jfoxrabinovitz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 403, in __init__
    grouper, exclusions, obj = get_grouper(
  File "C:\Users\jfoxrabinovitz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 617, in get_grouper
    Grouping(
  File "C:\Users\jfoxrabinovitz\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 345, in __init__
    raise ValueError(f"Grouper for '{t}' not 1-dimensional")
ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional
```

Comment: Do you mean `(df['A'] - df['B']).groupby(df['C']).mean()` ?

Comment: @anky. Apparently I did. Is this a duplicate? It's gotta be. I'm still new enough to pandas that I don't know how to search properly. Alternatively, if you post an answer, I'll be happy to accept.

Comment: `g['A'].mean() - g['B'].mean()` also works.

Comment: @anky. What to do if the index is not 1-D?

Comment: @anky. I've rewritten the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `series.groupby` for this usecase which is faster than `dataframe.groupby`.

Since we already have a calculated series and we get the mean of the result using a grouper column, its better we use the grouper column in the `series.groupby` and then `.mean()` which aggregates the results:

```
(df['A'] - df['B']).groupby(df['C']).mean()
```

---

EDIT:

For multiple keys, you can use [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to assign a helper column and use `dataframe.groupby` to group on multiple keys:

```
df.assign(k=(df['A'] - df['B'])).groupby(['C','D'])['k'].mean()
#k is our helper column(series)
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, `assign` creates a new df with the same underlying data and a new helper column. The original df is unaffected unless I start assigning stuff to the helper df?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Exactly, it creates a copy of the df with the new column. One can avoid by setting a new column and grouping later if memory is an issue. breaking it down into 2 steps :) BDW assign can also replace existing columns with a copy (if that helps try `df.assign(A=1)` to replicate)